# Split a parquet file in smaller chunks using dask

Tags: python, data-science, dask

I am trying to split a parquet file using DASK with the following piece of code

```
import dask.dataframe as pd
df = pd.read_parquet(dataset_path, chunksize="100MB")
df.repartition(partition_size="100MB")
pd.to_parquet(df,output_path)
```

I have only one physical file in input, i.e. file.parquet

The output of this script is as well only one file, i.e. part.0.parquet.

Based on the partition_size & chunksize parameters, I should have multiple files in output

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`df.repartition(partition_size="100MB")` returns a **Dask Dataframe**.

You have to write :

```
df = df.repartition(partition_size="100MB")
```

You can check the number of partitions created looking at `df.npartitions`

Also, you can use the following to write your parquet files :

```
df.to_parquet(output_path)
```

Because Parquet files are meant to deal with **large files**, you should also consider using the argument `compression=` when writing you parquet files.

You should get what you **expect**.

**NB:** Writing `import dask.dataframe as pd` is missleading because `import dask.dataframe as dd` is commonly used

Comment: Chunksize is being deprecated. How could I get the same example by the new available features?

Comment: You don't have to use chunksize; dask is meant to handle very large files